# React function freezing website when dispatched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I passed a function to the child to check a checkbox and then to set `setDispatch(true)`, the problem is that when I check the checkbox everything freezes and the website stops until I close and open again.

the function:

```
      const [selectedChkBx, setSelectedChkBx] = useState({ arrayOfOrders: [] });
      const onCheckboxBtnClick = (selected) => {

      const index = selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.indexOf(selected);
        if (index < 0) {

            selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.push(selected);
        } else {
            selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.splice(index, 1);
        }
       
        setSelectedChkBx(selectedChkBx)
        toggleDispatchButton()
         

    };

     const toggleDispatchButton = () => {
        if (selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.length == 0) {
             setDispatchButtonDisplay(false)
        }
        else {
             setDispatchButtonDisplay(true)
        }
       

    }
```

Child Component:

```
       <form style={{ display: 'block' }} >   
                <Row sm={1} md={2} lg={3}>   
                  {ordersDisplay.map((value, key) => {

                            
                            return (
                                <motion.div key={value.id} layout>
                                    <DeliveryQueueComp
                                        selectedChkBx={selectedChkBx}
                                        toggleDispatchButton={toggleDispatchButton}
                                        setDispatchButtonDisplay={setDispatchButtonDisplay}
                                        value={value} 
                                        onCheckboxBtnClick={onCheckboxBtnClick} 
                                 />

                                </motion.div>
                            )
                        })

                        }

                        </Row>  </form>
```

DeliveryQueueComp Code:

```
             <div
                    className={styles1.checkBox}
                    style={{ background: selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.includes(value.id) ? 
                      '#f84e5f' : 'transparent' }}
                    onClick={() => { onCheckboxBtnClick(value.id) }}
                     >
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} style={{ fontSize: '10px', opacity: 
                     selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.includes(value.id) ? '1' : '0' }} />
             </div>
```

If I remove toggleDispatchButtonDisplay, it works but then after a while the page freezes again.
Any thoughts about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide `setDispatch` code I don't know what it does, but for the rest I think I know why it's not working.

You're assigning the array and then set it to the state. If you want to do this that way you should only do a `forceUpdate` instead of a setState (as it has already been mutated by `push` and `splice`).

To properly update your state array you can do it like this

```
const onCheckboxBtnClick = (selected) => {
    const index = selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.indexOf(selected);
    if (index < 0) {
      //the spread in array creates a new array thus not editing the state
      setSelectedChkBx({
        arrayOfOrders: [...selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders, selected]
      });
    } else {
      // same thing for the filter here
      setSelectedChkBx({
        arrayOfOrders: selectedChkBx.arrayOfOrders.filter(
          (value) => value !== selected
        )
      });
    }

    toggleDispatchButton();
  };
```

Here is the sandbox of your code https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-kalam-ntc7n7

Comment: Hello, the setDispatch is a useState just to toggle between true and false, I'll try your code now